# Display all posts in current category

Tags: php, categories

I am looking to create a behavior as shown in the following link:

http://www.javaexperience.com/java-role-of-serialversionuid-in-serialization/

Here all posts from the same category are being displayed. Currently, it is handwritten HTML code, I want to mimic this behavior using PHP code in my single.php.

[image: posts]

Following is the code I have written so far

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
   <ul>

query_posts('cat='.$category);
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   <li><a href="get_permalink( $id );">the_title();</a></li>
endwhile; endif;
   </ul>
<br/>

?>
```

Can someone help in making it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$PozCat = get_category ($cat);
$PozCat->id // give to us current cat id.
```

Then use this hook in your query:

```
<ul>
   <?php
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $PozCat = get_category ($cat);
    //$PozCat->id
    query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&cat='.$PozCat->id);
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: works great, except for `the_permalink()` typo

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using Wp_query() by passing the category name as an argument:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=mycategory&showposts=-1'); ?>

<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

<?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```